# What scope kendo templates are executed in?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have a kendo template like this:

```
<script id="rowTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
        <tr data-uid="#: uid #" role="row">
        <td role="gridcell">#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(WhenDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 'dd MMM yyyy') #</td>
        <td role="gridcell">#= Activity #</td>
        <td role="gridcell">#= Description #</td>
        <td role="gridcell">#if (isButtonShown(Activity)){# #= editTemplate # #}#</td>
        <td role="gridcell">#if (isButtonShown(Activity)){# #= delTemplate # #}#</td>
        </tr>
</script>
```

You can see that it calls `isButtonShown` function. The only way I can make this work is by putting `isButtonShown` function in the global scope, which I, obviously, want to avoid. Where can I define this function so that it's available when the template is compiled (apart from the global scope)?

Same question applies to `editTemplate` and `delTemplate`, those are also currently defined globally so they are visible to the template.

`WhenDate`, `Activity` and `Description` all are properties of entities that come from the data source the kendo grid is bound to.

Here is how the tempalate is referenced in javascript:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    rowTemplate: kendo.template($("#rowTemplate").html()),
    ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test this yourself with this code in the console:

```
kendo.template('#debugger#')({x:1});
```

Then your browser should break into the compiled template function, which looks like this:

```
(function(data
/**/) {
var o,e=kendo.htmlEncode;with(data){o='';debugger;o+='';}return o;
})
```

When your template runs, `data` is the passed in object `{x:1}` and `this` is `window`.

---

The easiest thing to do is make your function accessible to global scope, but maybe put it in a namespace object, like `app.utils.isButtonShown`

Though understandably you probably don't want to pollute global scope. Your object passed in as `data` (the items displayed in your grid) are probably in a `DataSource` so you might be able to call `.parent()` repeatedly to traverse up the observable hierarchy. That might get you to someplace where you can add your function.

Comment: Thank you this is useful. I ended up reworking the logic to move the function from the client to the server and exposing it as a property on the data source entity. You of course could not have known that this is a possibility because you have not seen my code. Still your answer gives tools to investigate similar issues in future, I did not know the neat trick you described at the top of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is possible other than putting it in the global scope.

Could you instead loop through your data before binding it to the grid and set a property 'isButtonShown' based on the Activity? Then it would just be a matter of checking property in your template rather than calling a function.